# Android ViewModelProviders устарел, используйте ViewModelProvider

Tags: android, kotlin

Учусь по книжке, которая видимо немножко отстала от текущих методик. Да и к слову, совсем не понимаю, что здесь происходит:

```
private val listViewModel: ListViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться, а так-же объясните как переписать это, чтобы все заработало). Заранее, огромное спасибо)

Comment: А что именно не работает-то?

Comment: ViewModelProviders устарел и теперь не используется. Вместо него используется ViewModelProvider. Только он дополнительно требует внести ViewModelProvider.Factory, о котором в книжке не слова не говориться. По офф документации с моим уровнем знаний, я уже весь мозг себе сломал и совсем не могу одуплить)

Comment: Вы di какой-либо (dagger например) используете, или пока что без этого?

Comment: Тут только джет пак. Это lifecyle. Я загрузил старую версию в проект и теперь работает, только перечеркнуто. Хотелось бы узнать, что за Factory такой и как его создать. Я совсем зеленый еще. Может это вообще лишнее? И есть какой-то другой способ, чтобы не сбрасывалась информация при изменении конфигурации устройства?

Comment: Фигня в том, что я не углублялся в эти дебри, ибо когда-то давно нашел удобное и простое решение. Но это решение завязано на di... если более или менее быстро вникну в то, как это сделать - напишу ответ. Желаю удачи в Вашем начинании))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57495788/8389574

Answer (score -1):

Подключаем

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment

Используем

```
val model by viewModels<ListViewModel>()
```